# Magento 2.4: Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: upgrade, elasticsearch, magento2.4, setup-di-compile, deploy

We have installed Magento 2.4 on our local machine. After installing, we have got the below error when doing the `setup:upgrade`

> Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found
> in your cluster

So we have disabled the elastic search module via `config.php`. After disabling the elastic search, we can successfully upgrade and run the deployment without any issues.

However, we are not able to create a product in admin as its keep loading and getting the below error in console.

[image]

We have try reindex but the below indexer is not running.

> Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive
> nodes found in your cluster

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the product page loading issue. When checking the attribute code, I have entered the code as `links`, after deleting this attribute the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is Elastic search issue.

Check is working or not using below command

> systemctl status elasticsearch.service